# How select everything using IN statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to filter some data using IN statement    like :

```
select * from mytable t where t.field in ( 'some statement' )
```

What should i write instead of `'some statement'`  to take all data from `mytable`

I am interested in how can i do it if `t.field` is `number` type and if `t.field` is `varchar2` type

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: filter by some of the data contained in the field

Comment: All data from the table? Well, that's not what I would call filtering. The pointless query with an `IN` clause would be: `select * from mytable t where t.field in (select t.field from dual)`. This makes the subquery correlated, which is uncommon for an `IN` clause. But as mentioned this query is pointless anyway :-)

Comment: thank you man it is working .     I just have  check if my select returns any value i will filter   IN ( some values ) but if my select return null i want to take    IN ( everything )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from mytable t where t.field in ( select field from mytable )
```

You have to be aware that **null** values in **field** will result in problems. The given SQL will have the identical result to

```
select * from mytable t
```

as long as field is not null.

It doenst matter if field is **number** or **varchar2**.

Answer (score 1):

You made it look like you wanted a *statement* in

```
select * from mytable t where t.field in ( 'some statement' )
```

But from your comment I gather this is not necessary. So it can be even:

```
select * from mytable t where t.field in (t.field)
```

Oracle's optimizer will see `where t.field = t.field` and re-write this query internally to `where t.field is not null` in case `field` is nullable or drop the where clause completely in case `field` is not nullable.

So this is about as quick as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from myTable t where t.field1 = 'AAA' and t.field2 in (select max(field2) from myTable where field1= 'AAA');
```

It helps maybe.

Comment: This will definitely not return all values because all rows where t.field1 is != 'AAA' or t.field1 IS NULL or t.field2 is NULL or t.field2 is != MAX(t.field2).